# Open or close cd-drive using cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-7, windows-10

Whether there is any way to close and open cd-drive using cmd?

I can open it like this:

```
powershell (New-Object -com "WMPlayer.OCX.7").cdromcollection.item(0).eject()
```

But idk how to close it

> (Of course I can push it in, but i mean how i can close it with cmd)

Comment: Duplicate of: https://superuser.com/questions/515464/how-to-close-the-optical-drive-tray-in-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found on Google with keywords :

> powershell close cd rom drive

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/11/12/pstip-ejecting-and-closing-cdrom-drive-the-powershell-way/

Answer (score 0):

```
do
Dim ts
Dim strDriveLetter
Dim intDriveLetter
Dim fs 'As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Const CDROM = 4
On Error Resume Next
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strDriveLetter = ""
For intDriveLetter = Asc("A") To Asc("Z")
Err.Clear
If fs.GetDrive(Chr(intDriveLetter)).DriveType = CDROM Then
If Err.Number = 0 Then
strDriveLetter = Chr(intDriveLetter)
Exit For
End If
End If
Next
Set oWMP = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7" )
Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection
For d = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
colCDROMs.Item(d).Eject
Next 'null

For d = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1
colCDROMs.Item(d).Eject
Next 'null

set owmp = nothing
set colCDROMs = nothing
loop
```

save as .vbs
you might have to disable antivirus

Comment: The question specifically asks about doing this in cmd, i.e. `cmd.exe` or the Windows Command Prompt. What you've submitted is a Visual Basic Script. In order for this to be able to run from cmd, you need [edit] your answer, such that it includes sufficient information for future readers to be able to know how to run it from that particular interface.